Создание драйвера QMYSQL на Windows: No SBOM project name was set
Я пытался создать драйвер QMYSQL, используя официальный сайт: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/sql-driver.html#qmysql. Я ввожу в командную строку следующее:
qt-cmake -G Ninja "C:\Qt1\6.8.1\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:\Qt1\6.8.1\msvc2022_64" -DMySQL_ROOT="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0"

и я получаю это:
CMake Error at C:/Qt1/6.8.1/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/QtPublicSbomHelpers.cmake:2552 (message):
  No SBOM project name was set.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Qt1/6.8.1/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/QtPublicSbomHelpers.cmake:2542 (_qt_internal_sbom_get_root_project_name_lower_case)
  C:/Qt1/6.8.1/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/QtPublicSbomHelpers.cmake:2636 (_qt_internal_sbom_get_root_project_name_for_spdx_id)
  C:/Qt1/6.8.1/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/QtPublicSbomHelpers.cmake:2603 (_qt_internal_sbom_generate_target_package_spdx_id)
  C:/Qt1/6.8.1/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/QtPublicSbomHelpers.cmake:1926 (_qt_internal_sbom_record_target_spdx_id)
  C:/Qt1/6.8.1/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/QtPluginHelpers.cmake:446 (_qt_internal_extend_sbom)
  mysql/CMakeLists.txt:8 (qt_internal_add_plugin)

Я попытался добавить эту команду в конец моего запроса:
-DQT_NO_CREATE_SBOM=ON

Также я попытался добавить это:
set(QT_SBOM_PROJECT_NAME "mysql_driver")

в CMakeList.txt из:
C:\Qt1\6.8.1\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql

Я не знаю, что делать.

начните с формулировки заголовка вопроса

@aleksandrbarakin, не понимаю, что не так с заголовком

после правки - уже лучше.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-131799

bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-131799:

Если SBOM не требуется для проекта sqldrivers, обходным путем является настройка с помощью -no-sbom или -DQT_GENERATE_SBOM=OFF.

~/qt/bin/qt-configure-module ~/qtbase_src/src/plugins/sqldrivers -no-sbom

или
~/qt/bin/qt-configure-module ~/qtbase_src/src/plugins/sqldrivers -- -DQT_GENERATE_SBOM=OFF

